# Fast convolution of a sparse 2D array with another 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution

I have two 2D arrays (say, `A` and `B`) and have to compute the convolution between them frequently; this operation is the bottleneck of my code. `A` is sparse and changes from convolution to convolution, while `B` is dense, but constant along the run.

Currently I'm doing the following, using `numpy`:

```
result = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.fft2(A)*B_FT)
```

where `B_FT = np.fft.fft2(B)` is the Fourier transform of `B` and is only computed once.

My question is, is there a way to exploit the fact that `A` is sparse and make the convolution operation faster? If `A` is sparse, computing the convolution in the direct space (rather than the Fourier space) must be much faster, however, it may not worth it due to the overhead of the Python interpreter. I was wondering therefore whether there are any compiled libraries which would support it.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve

Comment: I have tried it and looks slower than the method I'm using currently. Also, there are no options to wrap the operation, i.e. consider periodic arrays.

Comment: If your array is very sparse (say a few `1`s in a sea of `0`s) and the convolution not overly broad (i.e. limited in the spatial domain) , then except for the rare `1`s close to one another (needs collision detection) , each `1` just becomes a copy of the convolved waveform in the vicinity of the `1`.  The question is what is the physical meaning of the convolution and does it give you any useful insights you couldn't get from convolving a single `1` with array B.

Comment: also see http://www.spiral.net/software/sfft.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_Fourier_transform